# Should I worry about too many repetitive image downloads?

Tags: javascript, html, image, http

I have a simple HTML page with some javascript that continuously feeds an image control with images from a camera. My concern is that when I'm in Google Chrome, and am looking at the Resources, it is filling up with the same image filename over and over - every new refreshed image seems to be creating a copy.

Should I be worried about this? Is there a possibility that something might happen such as cache full or anything along those lines? Or would browsers respect this and handle it accordingly?

Just now, as I'm typing this question, Google Chrome's dev panel disappeared on this page of mine, as if it did in fact get overloaded with images. So I'm assuming this is not good. However the stream of images does continue to work as designed.

Currently it's on 2 frames per second, and here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Camera View</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var camurl = "";
        var fps = 1;
        var loop = null;

        onload = function() {
            camurl = getParameterByName('camurl');
            fps = getParameterByName('fps');            
            LoopProc();
        }

        onunload = function() {
            if (loop != null) 
                clearTimeout(loop);
        }

        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        function DelayTime() {
            if (fps < 1) fps = 1;
            return (1000 / fps);
        }

        function NewUrl() {
            return camurl + "#time=" + new Date().getTime();
        }

        function LoopProc() {
            document.getElementById("CamImage").src = NewUrl();
            loop = setTimeout('LoopProc();', DelayTime());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="CamImage" src="" alt="" />
</body>
</html>
```

And a sample call to this page:

```
http://localhost:8081/?fps=2&camurl=http://192.168.1.150/image.jpg
```

Note that I am using a trick for the cache - in the function `NewUrl()` I'm adding `#time=[datetime]` so that the cache will think it's a new image.

You can test this actually on any image on the net, by using another image URL than the `camurl` in the query string. Doesn't necessarily have to be a camera to test this scenario.

---

**UPDATE**

After running for 20 hours now, I have no issues at all in the web browser (Google Chrome) at a frame rate of 3 fps. That's ~3,600 frames, each being ~165 KB. So that makes it over half a gig downloaded - with no issues in the browser at all. But the dev tools crashed not even 30 minutes after being opened.

Comment: So it's normal behavior, and each image is indeed being cached. But the browser should be able to handle that, I'd be surprised if it crashed.

Comment: That's what I was hoping and expecting to hear, I'm just looking for technical insight as to why it would/wouldn't work out.

Comment: that's going to be a harddrive problem I think, I don't think there's anything into memory (yeah, besides pointers)

Comment: @Sebas And I'm assuming that most or all browsers have a cache size limit

Comment: the images are not being effectively cached because each one is a unique url. the cache allocation recycles itself by shoving out other resources, some of which your site might use... it's also enough to crash devtools or firebug's network tab eventually.

Comment: "I'm adding `#time=[datetime]` so that the cache will think it's a new image." will not work because the fragment is not sent to the server, and is not used in the cache (except in some Safari versions).

Comment: Not exactly. IE for example is know to have a bug and removes loaded images from the RAM/cache only when the whole page is unloaded.

Comment: @Mike Actually I'm having rather opposite results - it works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but isn't working in IE or Safari

Comment: And the whole reason I'm building this in the first place is to make the cameras visible via mobile devices :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Url is the same for each image, it should work with no issues whatsoever as the new image will replace the old in the cache. The problem you're likely to hit is that you don't ever want the image retrieved from the cache, hence fudging the urls.

If you *do* continue to fudge the urls, the browser shouldn't crash but you will force (useful) resources out of the cache when it reaches capacity.

The ideal solution is to set the appropriate `cache-control` headers when retrieving the image to tell the browser not to store the image.

If the issue is that your source for the images doesn't include cache control headers and you can't modify it, consider proxying the image through [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) with the [HttpHeadersMore](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule) module which would allow you to decorate the response any way you like.

It's worth noting that Firebug/Chrome dev tools will die (eventually) with enough requests.

Comment: Actually I am using my web server as a gateway / central access point to connect to all the cameras - rather than directly to each URL. Therefore I do have control of the headers - another advantage of streaming them through a central server because the cameras themselves cannot be modified :) Well they can, but that's a firmware hack that I'm not willing to attempt

Comment: Ah, I had assumed you were hitting the cameras directly.  If you can tweak the headers, add the proper cache-control and don't fudge the url - you should have no issues.

Comment: You can assume that because my example above has a direct IP, but really that address is too long so I re-wrote it to a simple direct path.